# Datatable does not reinitializes properly when reloaded to display new saved record

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, datatable

I have a datatable where it gets populated with data from the database. When the web page loads I call my Bind() function and this function populates the datatable with data as well as it initializes the datatable .

I also have a modal popup where users can add records. When they click the save button, it saves the record and I make an attempt to repopulate and reinitialize the data table.

The problem is that when I reinitialize the datatable the second time (on the button click), the datatable does not get reinitialized properly. It displays the headings after every record (see picture below). Please note that this only happens on the button click.

This my code so far:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var dataTable;
    Bind();

    function Bind() {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "Clubs.aspx/GetCustomers",
            data: '{}',
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: OnSuccess,
            failure: function (response) {
                alert(response.d);
            },
            error: function (response) {
                alert(response.d);
            }
        });
    }

function OnSuccess(response) {
    var xmlDoc = $.parseXML(response.d);
    var xml = $(xmlDoc);
    var customers = xml.find("Table");
    var row = $("[id*=gvCustomers] tr:last-child").clone(true);
    $("[id*=gvCustomers] tr").not($("[id*=gvCustomers] tr:first-child")).remove();
    $.each(customers, function () {
        var customer = $(this);
        $("td", row).eq(0).html($(this).find("ClubID").text());
        $("td", row).eq(1).html($(this).find("ClubName").text());
        $("td", row).eq(2).html($(this).find("ClubEmail").text());
        $("td", row).eq(3).html("<span>" + $(this).find("ClubID").text() + "</span>");
        $("td", row).eq(4).html("<img id='btnID' src='/assets/img/edit.png' Style='width: 20px; height: 18px;'</>");
        $("[id*=gvCustomers]").append(row);
        row = $("[id*=gvCustomers] tr:last-child").clone(true);
    });
    //This is where I initializes my datatable
    $('table').each(function () {
        dataTable = $(this).prepend($("<thead style=background-color:#ff974d></thead>").append($(this).find("tr:eq(0)"))).DataTable({
            "responsive": true,
            "searching": true,
            "aaSorting": [],
            "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
            dom: 'lBfrtip',
            buttons: [
                {
                    extend: 'copy',
                    className: 'btn btn-success'
                },
                {
                    extend: 'excel',
                    text: 'Excel',
                    title: 'Centre Information',
                    className: 'btn btn-success',
                    orientation: 'portrait',
                    exportOptions: {
                        columns: [0, 1, 2]
                    }
                },
                {
                    extend: 'pdf',
                    text: 'PDF',
                    title: 'Centre Information',
                    className: 'btn btn-success',
                    orientation: 'portrait',
                    exportOptions: {
                        columns: [0, 1, 2]
                    }
                },
                {
                    extend: 'print',
                    text: 'PRINT',
                    title: 'Centre Information',
                    className: 'btn btn-success',
                    orientation: 'portrait',
                    exportOptions: {
                        columns: [0, 1, 2]
                    }
                }
            ]
        });
    });
}
    });
```

Then this is the code in the save button where I try to reinitialize the datatable

```
$("#btnSave").click(function () {
    dataTable.destroy();
    Bind();
    return false;
});
```

Please assist how I can reinitialize the datatable correctly.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try storing the DataTable in a variable and destroy that before rebinding the data.

So first create a varaible that can be accessed in both functions.

```
var dataTable;

function Bind() {
    //rest of code
}
```

Then assign the correct table to the variable

```
dataTable = $(this).prepend($("<thead style=background-color:#ff974d></thead>").append($(this).find("tr:eq(0)"))).DataTable({
```

And then on that button click destroy that

```
$("#btnSave").click(function () {
    dataTable.destroy();
    Bind();
    return false;
});
```

Comment: Ok so I tried tried this but it adds the header columns after every row. However, at least now I can see the records but like I said it keeps adding the header columns after every record. Any idea how I can fix this?

Comment: Not sure what you mean. I've tested with a simple html table without tje Ajax. It did not add an extra header row. So the problem might be in `OnSuccess` function. Do you have a sample xml?

Comment: I will have a look now and provide more feedback if I find something

Comment: Please see the updated code which include your suggestions.